# Receive SMS in node - undefined

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

How do I get data posted from Webhook into my node.js ? req.body seems not right because I'm getting undefined - Twilio doesn't have a lot of info on this - many help on how to send a message but very little on receiving....

```
const express = require('express');
const { MessagingResponse } = require('twilio').twiml;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(
    bodyParser.json({
        verify: (req, res, buf) => {
            req.rawBody = buf;
        },
    })
);
```

};

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);

var from = req.body.From;
var to = req.body.To;
var body = req.body.Body;
var num_media = req.body.NumMedia;
var city = req.body.FromCity;
var state = req.body.FromState;
var zip = req.body.FromZip;
const other = `${city} ${state} ${zip} atch: ${num_media}`;
console.log(from);
console.log(to);
console.log(body);
console.log(num_media);
console.log(city);
console.log(state);
console.log(zip);
console.log(other);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the problem.Instead of this:

```
app.use(
bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
        req.rawBody = buf;
    },
})
);
```

I used this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```